# Too much spacing in text

Tags: website-design, text, css

I did't know why I had so much spacing issues on my site, but i figured out that it is because of the "text-align" style property, which is set to "justified". This spreads out words in a row that has less words than other rows. I can fix it by switching align "left", but it doesn't look as good.

Does anyone know how to keep it justified, but fixing the spacing issue?
Thank you

Comment: The spacing is how the text is actually justified, so I don't see how this would be possible. You might be able to hack it, like User answered, but if your code needs hacks to work, you need to rethink what you're doing in the first place. Also, justified text is something I would avoid for any large amounts of copy on a website. You can use it in small amounts, but if all your text is justified, it can lead to readability issues for some users due to the gaps creating "rivers" of white space in your copy.

Comment: Hi Alex, could you [edit] your question to add a screenshot to show us what's wrong? We're visually-oriented kind of crowd :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try define css rule for text:

```
word-spacing: 0px;
```

If this is not sufficient, try to use negative values:

```
word-spacing: -5px;
```